# Deploy SSDT Tabular Model (1400) with Azure Analysis Services 1500

Tags: azure, deployment, tabular, azure-analysis-services

I am creating tabular models on SSDT. The maximum compatibility of SSDT is 1400. The supported compatibility of Azure Data Service is 1500. It is not letting me deploy the model because of compatibility issues. What is the solution for the same?

Thanks,
HV

Comment: Consider using [Tabular Editor](https://tabulareditor.github.io) instead of SSDT. It has full support for CL 1500 and Azure AS.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered your question on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5859d3e8-e562-4299-bedf-2e1a810233a5/deploy-ssdt-tabular-model-1400-with-azure-analysis-services-1500?forum=AzureAnalysisServices#4f4100b2-5fcd-42e8-873e-4079556b3c62) post.

I would suggest you update/download the latest version of SSDT and try the same.

After you update to the latest version of SSDT, you can create a tabular model with the compatibility level 1500.

[image]

And now, you can change the compatibility level from 1400 to 1500.

Right click on “Model.bim” file => select properties => Under Misc => change Compatibility Level
[image]

We are pleased to announce that SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Analysis Services now supports tabular models with 1500 compatibility level. The 1500 compatibility level is required to take advantage of the latest features for tabular models in Azure Analysis Services. You can download the latest SSDT VSIX for Visual Studio from the [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects).

To create a new tabular model project in SSDT, specify the 1500 compatibility level upon project creation. You can also upgrade an existing tabular project to 1500 in the properties window for the BIM file.

For more details, refer “[SSDT support for 1500 compatibility level](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/ssdt-support-for-1500-compatibility-level/)”.

Hope this helps.